# Python: Using code to write code - For a beginner

Tags: python, pygame, getattr

The issue I'm having right now is loading a bunch of sound files as their own objects in Pygame. You load a sound with this syntax:

```
sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('file.wav')
```

Say I have seven files, and I want them loaded and named sound1 - sound7. And I didn't want to load them each individually. If I didn't know it was flawed, I would try something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    new = 'sound' + str(i)
    new = pygame.mixer.Sound(str(new) + 'wav')
```

How would I go about making 'new' it's own variable, and not a string? I've read about getattr, but it's confusing. I would really like to know how to use functions and loops to dynamically create code, but so far I can't find anything useful to a beginner like myself. Using this as an example, would anybody like to explain in a simple way the ways you could go about creating code inside of code and turn strings into usable variables/objects?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to look into arrays - then you can refer to e.g. `sound[2]`

Comment: FYI, string formatting is usually nicer than string concatenation: `'sound' + str(i) === 'sound%s' % i`

Comment: I think this is a great example of a good beginner question- while you're very new, you tried a few approaches, did some research, and explained what you were looking for. Still, I recommend working all the way through some Python tutorials, which would introduce you to lists and dictionaries

Answer (score 6):

```
sounds = [] # list
for i in range(1, 8):
    sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound('sound' + str(i) + 'wav'))
```

Or

```
sounds = {} # dictionary
for i in range(1, 8):
    sounds[i] = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound' + str(i) + 'wav')
```

At first it seems you use the dictionary approach the same as the list approach, e.g. sounds[1] sounds[2] and so on, but you can also do this:

```
sounds = {} # dictionary
for i in range(1, 8):
    sounds['sound' + str(i)] = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound' + str(i) + 'wav')
```

And now sounds["sound1"] and so on work, for example.

Comment: Actually, the dictionary is unnecessary here but it would be _excellent_ in one use case: `sounds{"ding"} = pygame.mixer.Sound("ding.wav")` - then you can use the sound name to look up the sound, something like `sounds{"ding"}.play()`.

Comment: Right, if you just index it by number it's doing essentially the same thing, but if you'd prefer to index by other things, like the name of the sound, it's a big improvement

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays for this:

```
sound = []
for i in range(1,8):
    sound.append (pygame.mixer.Sound("sound%d.wav" % i))
# Now use sound[0..6] to reference sound[1..7].wav
```

That will load the files `sound1.wav` through `sound8.wav` - if your files are named differently, you just change the range and/or string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of loops in python the for-loop and the while-loop.  The for-loop is used to repeat something n number of times. The while-loop is used to repeat until something happens.  For-loops are useful for game programming as they often handle the frames the game displays. Each frame runs one time through a loop. The way you store a for-loop is with a list.  Here is an example of a basic loop you can familiarize yourself with:

```
he_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'apricots']
change = [1, 'pennies', 2, 'dimes', 3, 'quarters']

# this first kind of for-loop goes through a list
for number in the_count:
    print "This is count %d" % number

# same as above
for fruit in fruits:
    print "A fruit of type: %s" % fruit

# also we can go through mixed lists too
# notice we have to use %r since we don't know what's in it
for i in change:
    print "I got %r" % i

# we can also build lists, first start with an empty one
elements = []

# then use the range function to do 0 to 5 counts
for i in range(0, 6):
    print "Adding %d to the list." % i
    # append is a function that lists understand
    elements.append(i)

# now we can print them out too
for i in elements:
    print "Element was: %d" % i
```

You can learn more about loops and game programming in python here:
[programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=loops](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?lang=en&chapter=loops)